# Replacing TinyMCE content without select in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, select, focus, internet-explorer-11, tinymce-4

I have a TinyMCE editor whose content is divided into parts defined by ids. I want to be able to replace one specific part.

```html
<textarea id="myEditor">
    <div id="div1">Some intro</div>
    <div id="div2">Some initial content..</div>
    <div id="div3">Some outro</div>
</textarea>
```

I had this working nicely in Chrome with this function:

```javascript
function exchangeContent(id, content) {
    var editor= tinymce.get('myEditor');
    //Add the new content in div with the same ID so it can be replaced again.
    content = '<div id='+ id +'>'+ content +'</div>';
    //Select the content to replace
    editor.selection.select(editor.dom.select('div#' + id)[0]);
    //Replace content in editor.
    editor.setContent(editor.getContent().replace(editor.selection.getContent(), content));
}
```

, but in IE (v.11) this totally ruined the user experience. Each time `editor.selection.select(...)` was called, the cursor would move to the editor making it impossible to fill out an input fields without continuosuly having to re-focus it manually.

I have a solution below, if someone else has a better solution, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: So you basically already solved your own problem?

Comment: @Zenoo Yes. Posting to share and maybe save someone else some time and effort. Couldn't really find any info about the focus issue. And, as stated, wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works nicely for me in IE 11:

```javascript
function exchangeContent(id, content) {
    var editor= tinymce.get('myEditor');
    //Add the new content in div with the same ID so it can be replaced again.
    content = '<div id='+ id +'>'+ content +'</div>';
    //Getting and setting content without select.
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(editor.getContent(), "text/html")
    var replaceElem = doc.getElementById(id);
    editor.setContent(doc.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(
                               replaceElem.outerHTML, content));
}
```